# SSH port forwarding via jump host, ssh_config files and ONLY "ssh targethost"

Tags: ssh-tunneling, openssh, port-forwarding

**NB:** The OpenSSH clients I am using are all at **version 7.2**, so no [`RemoteCommand`](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6) available.

Assume the following setting:

1. machine `foo` is a jump host and provides access to host `bar` via its `localhost:10022`
2. `bar` sits inside a network inside of which we can access host `rdp` and access its RDP port (3389). I actually give the IP of `rdp` inside my command lines and configuration, but I presume that it is legit to use its name as long as name lookup works. For brevity I am using `rdp` here.

The goal is now to gain access to `rdp:3389` by connecting to `bar` via jump host `foo` and forward that to `localhost:33389` on the local machine from which I am invoking `ssh bar`.

```
[local:33389] --> {foo} --> {bar} --> [rdp:3389]
```

---

**Interlude**

I have solved this previously with PuTTY as follows:

1. create a connection to `foo` and configure a local forwarding `-L 33389:localhost:33389`, thus tying `localhost:33389` on the local machine to `localhost:33389` on `foo`.
2. use the following remote command to carry the port forwarding into the network inside of which `bar` sits by passing `ssh -L 33389:rdp:3389 -A bar`.
3. `Host bar` is configured *on* `foo` inside of `.ssh/config` to connect to `localhost:10022` and thereby end up on `bar` via the jump host.

The PuTTY configuration works like a charm, but it relies on a remote command to be executed. While a shell alias would be one way of going about this, I was wondering if there's a way to keep everything inside the `ssh_config(5)` used by my client, using `ProxyCommand`?

---

A rough equivalent of the above PuTTY configuration is this:

```
ssh -L 33389:localhost:33389 foo ssh -t -L 33389:rdp:3389 -p 10022 localhost
```

or, provided that `Host bar` is configured on `foo` to go through `localhost:10022` of `foo`:

```
ssh -L 33389:localhost:33389 foo ssh -t -L 33389:rdp:3389 bar
```

And this seems to get the job done.

But of course this is plenty to type and it would be neater to be able to put this *all* into the configuration file and simply type `ssh bar` on the local machine.

*With* `RemoteCommand` as introduced in OpenSSH 7.6 this seems to be rather trivial:

```
Host bar
    HostName foo
    RemoteCommand ssh -L 33389:rdp:3389 -A -p 10022 localhost
    LocalForward 33389 localhost:33389
```

... which should roughly translate to the `ssh` invocation shown above. But as mentioned before, I am using an older (packaged) version of OpenSSH without support for the `RemoteCommand` stanza.

Here's the attempt that seems to come closest to what I want to achieve.

```
Host bar
    HostName localhost
    Port 10022
    ProxyCommand ssh -L 33389:localhost:33389 -W %h:%p foo
    LocalForward 33389 rdp:3389
```

The idea being that on the local machine I will simply invoke `ssh bar`. In fact it works in that I end up on the shell prompt of `bar`, but the port forwarding doesn't work at all. While `sudo lsof -i|grep 3389` on the local machine gives me:

```
ssh       15271        accden    6u  IPv6 7933201      0t0  TCP localhost:33389 (LISTEN)
ssh       15271        accden    7u  IPv4 7933202      0t0  TCP localhost:33389 (LISTEN)
```

On the jump host I see nothing listening on any port containing `3389`.

Since `ProxyCommand` establishes the connection to `foo` and I am giving a `LocalForward` for the connection to `bar`, I'd expect this to work.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Goal is to use `ssh bar` to connect to `bar` and at the same time make `rdp:3389` available on the local machine as `localhost:33389`. Tweaking the `ssh_config(5)` files on the local machine and `foo` are allowed. Passing remote commands is not a valid answer, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, with your kind of setting, what *would* work, requiring *anyway* two ssh:

```
Host foo
    LocalForward 10022:bar:22

Host bar
    Hostname localhost
    Port 10022
    LocalForward 33389 rdp:3389

term1$ ssh foo # or use ssh -f -N -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes foo for background task
term2$ ssh bar
```

What you'd really need wouldn't be RemoteCommand but ProxyJump, really simplifying your configuration, with goal reached *only* with:

```
ssh -L 33389:rdp:3389 -J foo bar
```

Or the equivalent (only) configuration:

```
Host bar
    ProxyJump foo
    LocalForward 33389 rdp:3389
```

With zero intermediate port needed.

Unfortunately ProxyJump is available only starting from openssh 7.3

But it's [easily replaced with the `ProxyCommand`/`-W` combo](https://superuser.com/questions/1253960/replace-proxyjump-in-ssh-config) you were using before.

```
ssh -L 33389:rdp:3389 -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh foo -W %h:%p' bar
```

or as configuration file:

```
Host bar
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p foo
    LocalForward 33389 rdp:3389
```

There are still two ssh running: the hidden one is the one as `ProxyCommand` parameter still running on the local host doing the link using a pair of pipes with the main ssh, instead of an extra tcp port. Trying to involve the intermediate host in participating with the port forwarding is insecure or can clash (other users of foo can access the tunnel or use the same port), and prone to errors. Tunnel ends should always be kept on the client host if possible, where there's full control. Intermediate tunnels should either not exist or point to the next ssh entry point (that's the `-W` 's usage here).