# SSH jumphost does not work: "unkwnon option --J"

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I try to do a ssh jumphost with a command

```
ssh -J name@server1 name@server2
```

The answer is
`unkown option --J`

I try to reinstall ssh but it does not work. I am on ubuntu 16.04
Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: You say you used `-J name@server1` but the response is an unknown option `--J`. Are you sure you didn't use `--J` by mistake?

Comment: see my answer there about how to replace the -J option when not available on older versions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433923/ssh-port-forwarding-via-jump-host-ssh-config-files-and-only-ssh-targethost/434720#434720

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH port forwarding via jump host, ssh\_config files and ONLY "ssh targethost"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433923/ssh-port-forwarding-via-jump-host-ssh-config-files-and-only-ssh-targethost)